# Why did my Docker image size explode after creating a new image?

Tags: docker

I understand that this question has been asked multiple times. However, I believe that my question doesn't fit across those categories.

Here are the steps that I took -

1. I pulled docker ubuntu - `docker pull ubuntu`
   The size of the image was `77.8 MB`
2. Using that image, I created a new container by doing this - `docker run -it ubuntu`
3. I installed Ananconda Linux based on the instructions given over [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/linux/)
4. I made a new image by doing `docker commit sweet_herschel my_new_image`
   Now, when I do `docker images`, I find that the size of my image is `8.34 GB`

The reason I need a new image is that, I need a new image based on my container to convert it into a Singularity container that runs on my work HPC server.

Please let me know if I am missing any information or any further clarification is required.

Comment: Did you clean up anything after that install? There could be all kinds of left-over build debris. Worth scouring the filesystem with something like `ncdu` to see what happened.

Comment: As said by @teemu-risiko in his answer, Anaconda is big. If you only need command-line conda, then you may try to use miniconda instead. It should weight far less. For example, the [continuumio/miniconda3](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3) image weights about 200 Mo. *IMPORTANT* : beware of security risks when using a non-official image.

Comment: `docker commit` is almost never a best practice.  Read carefully the description of how you built the image, and ask how given those words only you'd recreate the image.  Can you build this image using a Dockerfile; and if so, can you [edit] the question to include the Dockerfile instead?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I need to do a lot more operations other than just install Anaconda. Therefore, the Docker file option isn't feasible for me.

Comment: Small anaconda takes ~5GB. 8GB for anaconda is reasonable. Our installation of anaconda is probably 20GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that result is not far off from the ballpark considering the [official anaconda 3 image](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3) takes 5.17GB. The anaconda environment is just that massive in size in general.

```
docker image ls | grep anaconda
continuumio/anaconda3  latest  9b2dbfa02e16  2 months ago  5.17GB
```

So as for your options, in all of them you have to accept that the image size will be in gigabytes.

#### First option

Just use the official image. 5.17GB is still less than 8GB.

#### Second option

Build the image from a Dockerfile, something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get -y update &&  apt-get -y install \
  libgl1-mesa-glx \
  libegl1-mesa \
  libxrandr2 \
  libxrandr2 \
  libxss1 \
  libxcursor1 \
  libxcomposite1 \
  libasound2 \
  libxi6 \
  libxtst6 \
  curl \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-Linux-x86_64.sh \
  && bash Anaconda3-2023.09-0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p $HOME/conda -f \
  && rm Anaconda3-2023.09-0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

I'm not anaconda expert so this might be missing something. The most important part is to remove the installer at the same RUN step, otherwise it will take up space in the layer even if removed later.

The size of the image with those instructions seems to be still 7.35GB, so there could be more stuff that needs cleaning. Still, it's a GB less.

#### Third option

If you really really want to do it with `docker commit`, do at least the following cleanup before:

1. Remove apt temporary files with `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`
2. Remove the anaconda installer that you downloaded (Anaconda3-2023.09-Linux-x86_64.sh)